# Using two functions in python, the first to generate numbers with for loop and the last to print all the numbers in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, printing

```py
def fun() :
  for i in range(1,10):
      return i


def main():
   fun()
   print(i)

main()
fun()
```

But the problem I have is that, it's printing only the last number but I want to print all numbers

Comment: Sorry, the code didn't appear in order here, but I guess you understand the arrangement of the code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include valid code, as well as the desired output. Do you want a single output of all numbers, as in ``[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]``, or mutiple outputs of one per number, as in ``1``, ``2``, ``3``, ...?

Comment: why do you capitalize all the function name and keyword? Python is case-sensitive, `def , for, fun, print` is different from `Def, For, Fun, Print`

Comment: I want multiple outputs of one per number,, 1,2,3,45,6,7,8,9 so I can be able to use the number as a value to do other things in the second function

Answer (score 2):

```
def fun():
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield i


def main():
    print(list(fun()))


main()
```

If you really want to use 2 functions instead of 1 (as @PaulZ. suggested),
you should use a generator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try it and it works, but I will like to use it as a generator and be able to use it as a value to do other things

Comment: You can do that

Comment: I have tried multiple ways but still getting the same result

Comment: what result and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def fun():
    for i in range(1,10):
        print(i)

def main():
    fun()
    
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want the number to be use as value to do other things in the second function